# PHP array runs function and pass variable to it

Tags: php, arrays

I am coding a bot for a game and I am now coding the handlers I want to call my array so it runs the function.

```
$handlers = array(
    "x" => function()
);

function function($m)
{
    echo "Var: " . $m . "\n";
}
```

When I call handlers I tried it like this:

```
$handlers("x");
```

So how can I pass the variable to the function.

Comment: `call_user_func($handlers['x'], $argument1, $argument2, ...)` or `call_user_func_array($handlers['x'], $argumentsArray)`

Comment: When I run it it says "Warning: Missing argument for ..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is the [call_user_func](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) function. Besides, in your `$handlers` array, the name of the function must be in quotation marks and you can not use the reserved keyword `function` as the name of the function! and you may access the array element using `[]` operator:

```
$handlers = array(
    "x" => '_function'
);

function _function($m)
{
    echo "Var: " . $m . "\n";
}

call_user_func($handlers['x'], "hello :)");
```

Comment: Thanks :), One more question how would I add to the array. array_push($handlers, 'y' => 'yFunction'); ?

Comment: @54.224.239.54 Your welcome :), To add to the array you may use `$handlers['y']='yFunction';`

Comment: Would this differ if it's in a class?

Comment: call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'joinRoom' not found or invalid function name :(

Comment: @54.224.239.54 For the case in which you have a method in a class then you may use `call_user_func(array($classname, 'methodName'));`.

Comment: I'm calling it from inside the class though.

Comment: @54.224.239.54 Then you may use the `call_user_func(array($this, 'methodName'));`.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, you can do it this way as well:

```
$handlers = array(
    "x" => 'test'
);

function test($m) {
    echo "Var: " . $m . "\n";
}

$handlers['x']("testing...");
```

Comment: By the way how would I add to the array. array_push($handlers, 'y' => 'yFunction'); ?

Comment: `$handlers['y'] = 'whatever';`